# Create a bucket if it's not already created on S3 for php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What i'm trying to do if file upload for the first time(when multiple files) then it should create a subfolder in that bucket and folder_name assigned with that particular ID. And next time when some files upload with in that same ID then files store in this folder should not create a new one. When ID change it can create a new subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

So if you are talking about creating a new "folders" in S3, this is not a problem since there are no such real "folders". What matters in an S3 bucket is the **key**.

Now, say you have a key `my/key`. You'll see a *directory-like* structure in the console, but it's actually all flat. Taken from [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html):

> Amazon S3 supports buckets and objects, and there is no hierarchy in Amazon S3. However, the prefixes and delimiters in an object key name enable the Amazon S3 console and the AWS SDKs to infer hierarchy and introduce the concept of folders.

---

So in your case, just change the key you are using (the "*folders*" will be automatically created)/